# How to create a fluidic list using css

Tags: html, css

Trying to create an adjustable menu lists, but in a scenario it is failing.
When selecting the list need to add a border of 3px which is breaking the below lists. Can any one please help me. I need that all the list items aligned properly if border added.

**CSS**

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul li {
    width:100px;
    float:left; 
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:10px;
}
.selected{
    border:3px solid red;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<ul>
    <li class="selected"> One </li>
    <li> Two </li>
    <li> Three </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li><li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
</ul>
```

This is what have tried:

[Demo List Link](http://jsfiddle.net/88a6E/44/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88a6E/46/)**

```
ul li {
 width:100px; 
 border:1px solid red;
 margin:10px; 
 display:inline-block; /*newly added and removed float property*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your css file.

```
*,
*:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or, add a transparent border of 2px around each li element.. asuming they already have a 1px border.

Edit:

Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Like others sugested, use `display: inline-block` or `display: inline` .

Answer (score 0):

Use `outline` instead of `border`.

http://jsfiddle.net/nw0q4z6z/

Comment: For only borders this is a good option, another one would be `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #f00` using the spread value (4th px value). But for more complex styles this won’t always be perfectly sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, compatibility is one argument in favor of `outline`, that’s true.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul li {
    width:100px;
    vertical-align:top;    /* This */
    display:inline-block;  /* and more importantly this */
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;` *as often as possible*. And also, add `vertical-align:top;` for it to look good.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88a6E/45/)

Answer (score 0):

You have many options.

The first option is to use an outline on the `.selected` element.

The second option is to apply a `box-sizing:border-box` on the parent element.

The third option is to use a `box-shadow` on the `.selected` element.

Personally I would go with the third option.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.selected {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 3px red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="selected">One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/88a6E/51/)

```
ul {list-style-type:none; 
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -moz-justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul.selected {
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100px;
    float:left; 
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:10px;

}
<ul class="selected">
    <li> One </li>
    <li> Two </li>
    <li> Three </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li><li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
    <li> Four </li>
</ul>
```

Try this code